# Django views for retreiving data from database and operating on that data

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-views

Currently, I am working on a project in Django and using PostgreSQL as a database.
So now database contains student information like id, name, gender, login time and logout time. Now if I want to get login and logout time of every student so I need to iterate through all the id's present on that specific date, how should I iterate the id's in views?

```
TodayStartdate = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  + " 00:00"

TodayEnddate = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  + " 23:59"

Timestamp = Students.objects.filter(id_timestamp__range=(TodayStartdate, TodayEnddate))

Login = Timestamp.first()
Logout = Timestamp.last()

print(Login)
print(Logout)
```

Comment: This is far too broad. Where exactly are you having trouble?

Comment: edited the post, so this is my Django's  view.py code and using this I get Object as output but I don't know how to apply the same logic for 'n' number of id's

Comment: i believe you will get a queryset of students that will have logged in and out on a specific date. So will you have use a loop in client side to iterate through your student objects. But if your looking to get these details for a specific student and obviously you'll need to pass in the student object ID.

Comment: but is it possible that I can retrieve all login logout  info of all students to calculate like total time login time of the day or total time student was in college/school depending on their login and logout time 

for e.g. 
result = logout - login 

so here i can get the time in hrs student was in the college.
so this process should repeat for multiple students.

Answer (score 0):

The QuerySet in Django is iterable, you simply do:

```
for elem in Timestamp.objects.all():
    #do something with elem.id
```